# Faitfully flatness over $B$ and flatness over $A$ equivalence

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

Let $B$ be an $A$-algebra, and let $E$ be a faithfully flat $B$-module. How can I show that $E$ is flat over $A$ if and only if $B$ is flat over $A$? (Liu, *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, Exercise 2.18.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $E \otimes_A - = E \otimes_B B \otimes_A - $ and due to $E$ being faithfully flat this functor is exact  if and only $B \otimes_A -$ is exact, that is, if and only if $B$ is flat over $A$.